# Do I need Gradle for Java extension while working with Dart&Flutter on VsCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, vscode-extensions

[Extension Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVP3S.png)

I realized that I have way too many unused extensions on VsCode and I started to delete the ones I don't need. I am currently working on Flutter & Dart, my folders include gradle files but I'm not sure if I need this extension or not or does it have any harm to uninstall this package, can anyone help?

I really am not sure about uninstalling or not.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to have gradle extension in vsc to work with Flutter & Dart

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to use this extension In VS Code :**Gradle for Java**

Answer (score 0):

no, you don't need ,

1. download JDK ,save environment.
2. download compare Gradle with JDK
3. add extension for dart and flutter